# Missing `test` rake tasks in Rails 3 project based on DataMapper template

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rake, datamapper

How can I get the test tasks back?

**Backstory:**  I didn't start with the default new rails project.  I'm using datamapper with dm-rails and used their boodstrap command:

```
rails new project_name -m http://datamapper.org/templates/rails.rb
```

My Rakefile is as follows:

```
require File.expand_path('../config/application', __FILE__)
require 'rake'

MyAppName::Application.load_tasks
```

Comment: No sure what you mean? If you create a new rails 3 project, rake -T show test and rake test runs the tests ...

Comment: Yes, the default new project will have the test tasks, but I didn't start with the default new project.  I'll add clarification.

Comment: Can you post the contents of your `Rakefile`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In a default Rails 3 project, `config/application.rb` contains `require 'rails/all'`, basically requiring all of the rails frameworks (ActiveRecord, ActiveResource, ActionController, ActionMailer, **TestUnit**, etc.)

The DataMapper template changes this. Since it doesn't use ActiveRecord, it can't `require 'rails/all'` without causing problems. The only default Rails component it actually keeps is ActionController. It puts in `require` statements for ActiveResource, ActionMailer, and TestUnit, but **comments them out by default**.

Long story short: uncomment the following line in `config/application.rb`:

```
require 'rails/test_unit/railtie'
```